# Expose on-prem application with Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have an on-premise API Service that needs to be access from the Internet. I want to secure it using `Azure API Management`.

My plan is to use `Azure AD Application Proxy` with `passthrough` pre-authentication to expose the API to the internet, then create a `Conditional Access` policy that denies access from all IPs except the IP of the `Azure API Management` instance. The exposing part works fine, but the `Conditional Access` policy doesn't seem to work.

In my `Conditional Access` policy I've selected `None` in `Users` assignment, my app in `Cloud apps or actions` assignment, in the `Conditions` assignment I have a `Named Location` that matches all countries including unknown. Under `Access controls` `Grant` is set to `Block access`. This rule should block all access to the application, but yet I'm able to access it through the public URL that was created by `Azure AD Application Proxy`.

I've also tried to use on-premise `API Management Gateway` to achieve same result, but it seems like it only works with on-prem requests and doesn't provide a way to route a request from the Internet to on-prem service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/application-proxy-faq#can-i-use-conditional-access-policies-for-applications-published-with-pass-through-authentication-) there's no way to enforce IP filtering using `Conditional Access` on `Azure AD Application Proxy` with `passthrough` pre-authentication:

> Conditional Access Policies are only enforced for successfully
> pre-authenticated users in Azure AD. Pass-through authentication
> doesn’t trigger Azure AD authentication, so Conditional Access
> Policies can't be enforced